# PowerShell Remove-Item don't remove files

Tags: powershell

I'm trying this `Remove-Item` to work, to make delete all xml file in my Source path of powershell script. It doesn't retrieve any error.. But it doesn't delete files either.

```
 Remove-Item –path $SourcePath* -include *.xml –recurse -force
```

The `SourcePath` is correct, because the script run fine in his previous part.

Why it doesn't delete files if it copy right in the destination folder result files?

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)][String]$SourcePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)][String]$DestinationPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)][ValidateSet("utf8")][String]$Encoding
)

$Files = Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -include *.xml -Recurse 

If ($Files.Count -gt 0) {

    If (!($DestinationPath.Substring($DestinationPath.Length - 1) -eq "\")) {
        $DestinationPath = $DestinationPath + "\" + $Files[0].Directory.Name + "\"
    }
    Else {
        $DestinationPath = $DestinationPath + $Files[0].Directory.Name + "\"
    }

    If (!(Test-Path -Path $DestinationPath)) {New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $DestinationPath | Out-Null}

    ForEach ($File in $Files) {
        Write-Host "Read and Convert $($File.Name)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        Get-Content $File.FullName  | Set-Content -Encoding $Encoding ($DestinationPath + $File.Name) -Force -Confirm:$false
        Remove-Item –path $SourcePath* -include *.xml –recurse -force
    }

    Write-Host "Conversion of $($Files.Count) Files to $Encoding in $DestinationPath completed" -ForegroundColor Green
}
Else {
    Write-Host "Source-Directory empty or invalid SourcePath." -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: Play around with `-Verbose` and `-WhatIf` to get commands to tell you more about what they (intend to) do.

Comment: I don't think it's the reason of your problem but `Remove-Item –path $SourcePath* -include *.xml –recurse -force` removes all `$Files` but is inside a `ForEach ($File in $Files)`. One execution of the command should be enough.